# Qt Jambi and threads

Tags: java, c++, qt, java-native-interface, qt-jambi

I'm trying to create a Qt widget in C++ as a child of a Jambi widget. Passing the parent's native pointer into a JNI method seems to be the straightforward approach, but Qt complains about creating the widget on a different thread than the parent.

Does JNI run methods on a different thread than the Java code? Or is Jambi doing some trickery behind the scenes and my Java Qt calls are really being invoked on a different thread? Or something else? What's going on here, and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quit writing your own JNI, use [The Qt Jambi Generator](http://doc.trolltech.com/qtjambi-4.5.0_01/com/trolltech/qt/qtjambi-generator.html) to generate stub for your C++ Widget and do all your code in java.